# How to display sql table in android textview

Tags: java, php, android, html, mysql

I'm trying to make an app for andoid which displays standings in sport leagues. So far I've made an online database and connected it to php. Now i would need some help connecting all together in a textview (or anything that would work as described).

My online database looks like this:
http://scoreboardbaza.site88.net/premierleague.php

My php file:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT mesto, ekipa, tekme, zmage, izenaceno, porazi, dosezenigoli,      dobljenigoli, golrazlika, tocke FROM premierleague";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th>Mesto</th><th>Ekipa</th><th>Tekme</th><th>Zmage</th><th>IzenaÄeno</th><th>Porazi</th><th>DoseÅ¾eni goli</th><th>Prejeti goli</th><th>Gol razlika</th><th>ToÄke</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td align='center'>".$row["mesto"]."</td><td>".$row["ekipa"]."     </td><td align='center'>".$row["tekme"]."</td><td align='center'>".$row["zmage"]."</td><td align='center'>".$row["izenaceno"]."</td><td align='center'>".$row["porazi"]."</td><td align='center'>".$row["dosezenigoli"]."</td><td align='center'>".$row["dobljenigoli"]."</td><td align='center'>".$row["golrazlika"]."</td><td align='center'>".$row["tocke"]."  </td></tr>";
       }
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

My "PremierLeagueLestvica.java" looks like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PremierLeagueLestvica extends ActionBarActivity { 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_premier_league_lestvica);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_premier_league_lestvica);




    //Gumb NAZAJ zav začetni zaslon
    Button btnNazaj = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNazaj);
    btnNazaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PremierLeagueLestvica.this, NogometActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_premier_league_lestvica, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And xml file "activity_premier_league_lestvica.xml":

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Premier League"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/back"/>

<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nazaj"
        android:id="@+id/btnNazaj"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textPL"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnNazaj"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: how do you read data from your database

Comment: I've added my php code

Comment: how to do you read data from your php application ?

Comment: looks like your question is about HTML and not XML. I changed the tag.

Comment: What do you mean by that Heshan?